# How do i set session storage on angular from a django token?

Tags: django, angular, angular7

There is an application(app A) currently on ground which i want to make an integration(app B) for.

App A is developed with Django.

App B is going to be developed using Angular.

So when a user is already logged in to app A, then he clicks the link to app B, a token should be generated for that user when redirected to App B. i need to store the token in storage and get data like email, username e.t.c. from it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the token to the url when you open the angular app. Then you can grab it out of the url using the following.

```
constructor() {
    private _route: ActivatedRoute
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if(params['token']) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('djangoToken', params['token'])
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can use this token in an API request to get the data you wan't from server.

```
this.http.get(`server_url/?token=${sessionStorage.getItem('djangoToken')}`).subscribe(
    data => {
        // Do something with your data...
    }
)
```

Comment: Are all this going to be in the data.service.ts file?

Comment: No the top part would be in your component. Probably app.component.ts given you want to call it on load. And then the http method would be inside your service. So once you get the token you can call the service with the token as an argument and get your data back.